# Android - Set seekbar progress always left to the thumb

Tags: android, seekbar

IF the progress is near the borders the progress line will be ahead or behind the thumb if padding and *thumboffset* is set for `seekbar`(See image):

[image]

```
    <SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/seekBar1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true" 
    android:thumbOffset="0dp"
    android:thumb="@drawable/meterknob"
    android:paddingLeft="25dp"
    android:paddingRight="25dp"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
        />
```

I want `seekbar` always like this!

[image]

How can I implement this. Please help me Thanks in advance

EDIT 
When I applied Karthika's code . I got like below image. The problem here is it is not touching its background image's borders. I have to start it from the starting of background image.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

set

```
   <SeekBar
            android:id="@+id/progressplay"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                     android:visibility="gone"
                android:background="@drawable/violetborderbox"
             android:thumb="@drawable/playbtn"
             android:progressDrawable="@drawable/seekbar_progress"

            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
             android:paddingLeft="35dp"

android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
             android:paddingRight="35dp"/>
```

inside your seeekbar

and the drawable file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@android:id/background"
        android:drawable="@color/violetbg"
        android:dither="true">
    </item>
    <item android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress">
        <clip>
            <shape>
                <gradient
                    android:startColor="#80028ac8"
                    android:centerColor="#80127fb1"
                    android:centerY="0.75"
                    android:endColor="#a004638f"
                    android:angle="270"
                />
            </shape>
        </clip>
    </item>
    <item
        android:id="@android:id/progress"
        android:drawable="@drawable/seekbar_progress_bg"
    />
</layer-list>
```

my result was

[image]

Comment: Thank you. But no change

Comment: Thank you for your time. I think slight change on your code may work. Up voting your answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73412/discussion-between-karthika-pb-and-user1767260).